# Different Images for Radio Buttons in Group by mvvmcross

Tags: android, image, xamarin, radio-button, mvvmcross

I'm using mvvmcross for android app. I'm trying to create group of dynamic radiobuttons with specific image for each button. Everything is going well except there are no images.

Parent axml:

```
<Mvx.MvxRadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textLanguage"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textLanguage"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/radioitem"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource LanguageImageList;SelectedItem SelectedLanguage" />
```

RadioItem.axml:

```
<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text Key; Bitmap Value, Converter=MvxImageConverter" />
```

My converter:

```
public class MvxImageConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, Bitmap>
{
    protected override Bitmap Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var imageLoader = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxLocalFileImageLoader<Bitmap>>();
        MvxImage<Bitmap> image = imageLoader.Load(value, true);
        return image.RawImage;
    }
}
```

In debugger convertor method is invoked and *image.RawImage* is not *null* or empty.

And finally viewModel:

```
    private string _selectedLanguage;
    public string SelectedLanguage
    {
        get { return _selectedLanguage; }
        set 
        { 
            _selectedLanguage = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedLanguage);
            LanguageChanged();
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> LanguageImageList
    {
        get { return new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "US", "res:lang_us_small" }, { "UK", "res:lang_uk_small" }, { "FR", "res:lang_fr_small" }, { "GE", "res:lang_ge_small" } }; }
    }
```

I tried different binding keywords instead of "Bitmap": "DrawableId", "DrawableName", "Image", "ImageUrl", "Button", "Style". No luck. In output I always see message that value could not be bound to specified keyword.

If I create static radio buttons in parent axml and give specific link to image to each radio button, I can see images but binding does not work i.e. setter of *SelectedLanguage* is not invoked. BTW I don't like this solution.

Is it possible in mvvmcross create a dynamic (or at least static) group of radio buttons with specific image for each button?

Desired picture:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/elIap.png

**UPDATE:** I've created sample project for simple reproduce: https://github.com/midmmi/mvvmcross_radio_buttons

Comment: Not sure I can help debug this without an executable example.. However, If you subclass `RadioButton` to provide your own `MyRadioButton` then provide a `public MyBitmap` property on that `MyRadioButton` then this may help you debug what is going on - you should be able to use the `MyRadioButton` view in your template and you should see `set` on `MyBitmap` being called.

Comment: I've just started with mvvmcross and .Net and might be missed something. I failed to find RadioButton class in sources. Only RadioGroup class with selectedIndex property. Could you please drop me a link to RadioButton class? Thank you.